# How to submit MutipartRequest data without file uploading in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I have a form having some textfield and an image upload option where i am able to browse the image and submit the  multipartrequest data but my requirement is the user has an option that he may or may not browse the image field at that time how to insert the multipartrequest data with the remaining field.

Below is my code:

```
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
String rootPath=FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
String url="some web service url"
if(imagePath!=null && imagePath!=rootPath){
request.setUrl(url);
request.addData("uploadedFile", image.getText(), "image/*");
request.setFilename("uploadedFile", uploadFileName);
request.setPost(true);
request.setFailSilently(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
request.getResponseData();
}
else{
imagePath=FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
request.setUrl(url);
request.addData("uploadedFile", uploadFileName, "image/*");
request.setPost(true);
request.setFailSilently(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
r.getResponseData();
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `addData` or `setFilename` in which case the request will still be a multipart but it will not submit the data.

Comment: I comment those two lines and try to save my data but its not not able to call my webService  method with the respective url its expecting multipart data to be passed

Comment: Below my webservice method----public void saveUser(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFileRef, 
            @RequestParam("fname") String fname)